# JClouds-Chef: IllegalAccessError on TokenType2?

Tags: java, chef-infra, jclouds

I am using the [JClouds-Chef](http://jclouds.apache.org/guides/chef/) API to bootstrap a Linux VM (`myapp01.me.example.com`) with Chef Client, and to then run the client and configure the VM with its app stack via a `typicalapp` role:

```
package com.me.myorg.chef;

import org.jclouds.Constants
import org.jclouds.ContextBuilder
import org.jclouds.chef.ChefContext
import org.jclouds.chef.ChefService
import org.jclouds.chef.config.ChefProperties
import org.jclouds.chef.domain.BootstrapConfig
import org.jclouds.chef.util.RunListBuilder
import org.jclouds.compute.domain.ExecResponse
import org.jclouds.compute.domain.OsFamily
import org.jclouds.domain.LoginCredentials
import org.jclouds.scriptbuilder.domain.Statement
import org.jclouds.ssh.SshClient
import org.jclouds.sshj.config.SshjSshClientModule

import com.google.common.base.Charsets
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet
import com.google.common.io.Files
import com.google.common.net.HostAndPort
import com.google.inject.Key
import com.google.inject.TypeLiteral

public class ChefProvisioner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChefProvisioner.provision()
    }

    public static provision() {
        String vmIp = "myapp01.me.example.com";     // A Linux VM living in our local vCenter
        String vmSshUsername = "admin";
        String vmSshPassword = "12345";

        String endpoint = "https://mychefserver";
        String client = "myuser";
        String validator = "chef-validator";
        String clientCredential = Files.toString(new File("C:\\Users\\myuser\\sandbox\\chef\\myuser.pem"), Charsets.UTF_8);
        String validatorCredential = Files.toString(new File("C:\\Users\\myuser\\sandbox\\chef\\chef-validator.pem"), Charsets.UTF_8);

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(ChefProperties.CHEF_VALIDATOR_NAME, validator);
        props.put(ChefProperties.CHEF_VALIDATOR_CREDENTIAL, validatorCredential);
        props.put(Constants.PROPERTY_RELAX_HOSTNAME, "true");
        props.put(Constants.PROPERTY_TRUST_ALL_CERTS, "true");

        ChefContext ctx = ContextBuilder.newBuilder("chef")
            .endpoint(endpoint)
            .credentials(client, clientCredential)
            .overrides(props)
            .modules(ImmutableSet.of(new SshjSshClientModule())) //
            .buildView(ChefContext.class);
        ChefService chef = ctx.getChefService();

        List<String> runlist = new RunListBuilder().addRole("typicalapp").build();
        BootstrapConfig bootstrapConfig = BootstrapConfig.builder().runlist(runlist).build();

        chef.updateBootstrapConfigForGroup("jclouds-chef", bootstrapConfig);
        Statement bootstrap = chef.createBootstrapScriptForGroup("jclouds-chef");

        SshClient.Factory sshFactory = ctx.unwrap().utils()
            .injector().getInstance(Key.get(new TypeLiteral<SshClient.Factory>() {}));
        SshClient ssh = sshFactory.create(HostAndPort.fromParts(vmIp, 22),
        LoginCredentials.builder().user(vmSshUsername).password(vmSshPassword).build());

        ssh.connect();
        try {
            String rawScript = bootstrap.render(OsFamily.UNIX);
            ExecResponse result = ssh.exec(rawScript);
        } finally {
            ssh.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.jclouds.apis.ApiMetadata: Provider org.jclouds.openstack.swift.SwiftApiMetadata could not be instantiated: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class com.google.common.reflect.TypeResolver from class org.jclouds.util.TypeToken2
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:224)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:181)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:377)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:445)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableCollection$Builder.addAll(ImmutableCollection.java:323)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet$Builder.addAll(ImmutableSet.java:633)
    at org.jclouds.apis.Apis.all(Apis.java:72)
    at org.jclouds.apis.Apis.withId(Apis.java:89)
    at org.jclouds.ContextBuilder.newBuilder(ContextBuilder.java:168)
    at org.jclouds.ContextBuilder$newBuilder.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at com.me.myorg.chef.ChefProvisioner.provision(ChefProvisioner.groovy:51)
    at com.me.myorg.chef.ChefProvisioner$provision.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at com.me.myorg.chef.ChefProvisioner.main(ChefProvisioner.groovy:27)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class com.google.common.reflect.TypeResolver from class org.jclouds.util.TypeToken2
    at org.jclouds.util.TypeToken2.where(TypeToken2.java:47)
    at org.jclouds.rest.internal.BaseRestApiMetadata.contextToken(BaseRestApiMetadata.java:60)
    at org.jclouds.rest.internal.BaseRestApiMetadata$Builder.<init>(BaseRestApiMetadata.java:74)
    at org.jclouds.openstack.swift.SwiftApiMetadata$Builder.<init>(SwiftApiMetadata.java:85)
    at org.jclouds.openstack.swift.SwiftApiMetadata$Builder.<init>(SwiftApiMetadata.java:81)
    at org.jclouds.openstack.swift.SwiftApiMetadata$ConcreteBuilder.<init>(SwiftApiMetadata.java:108)
    at org.jclouds.openstack.swift.SwiftApiMetadata$ConcreteBuilder.<init>(SwiftApiMetadata.java:108)
    at org.jclouds.openstack.swift.SwiftApiMetadata.<init>(SwiftApiMetadata.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:373)
    ... 16 more
```

Any ideas as to what is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need the following, in order to be able to bootstrap your VM:

- The ip address of the VM. It must be reachable, have the port 22 open (as the bootstrap will be done via SSH) and have access to the Internet so it can install Ruby and Chef.
- A client in the Chef Server and its corresponding private key. That client is used by jclouds to perform the operations against the Chef Server REST API.
- The validator certificate. That certificate will be uploaded to the node so it can self-register in the Chef Server.

In this case, as the jclouds ComputeService is not being used, you'll have to manually instantiate an SSH client to connect to the virtual machine, but it should be pretty straightforward.

In the example you mention, the Git repo is cloned when using ChefSolo, but since you have a Chef Server the only thing you need to do is to configure the connection and the desired run list and attributes.

A minimal program to do that would require the following dependencies:

```xml
<!-- Required dependencies -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.driver</groupId>
    <artifactId>jclouds-sshj</artifactId>
    <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>chef</artifactId>
    <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

And it could be something like the following:

**Update:** I've changed the configuration to match the provided *knife.rb* configuration, and also added a couple properties to avoid SSL errors, as your Chef endpoint is https.

```java
// Configuration
String vmIp = "vm-ip";
String vmSshUsername = "root";
String vmSshPassword = "foo";

String endpoint = "https://mychefserver.example.com";
String client = "myuser";
String validator = "chef-validator";
String clientCredential = Files.toString(new File("/home/myuser/.chef/myuser.pem"), Charsets.UTF_8);
String validatorCredential = Files.toString(new File("/home/myuser/.chef/chef-validator.pem"), Charsets.UTF_8);

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(ChefProperties.CHEF_VALIDATOR_NAME, validator);
props.put(ChefProperties.CHEF_VALIDATOR_CREDENTIAL, validatorCredential);
props.put(Constants.PROPERTY_RELAX_HOSTNAME, "true");
props.put(Constants.PROPERTY_TRUST_ALL_CERTS, "true");

/* *** First, create the context to connect to the Chef Server *** */

// Create the context and configure the SSH driver to use. sshj in this example
ChefContext ctx = ContextBuilder.newBuilder("chef")
    .endpoint(endpoint)
    .credentials(client, clientCredential)
    .overrides(props)
    .modules(ImmutableSet.of(new SshjSshClientModule())) //
    .buildView(ChefContext.class);
CherService chef = ctx.getChefService();

/* *** Second, generate the bootstrap script *** */

// Generate the bootsrap configuration
List<String> runlist = new RunListBuilder().addRole("typicalapp").build();
BootstrapConfig bootstrapConfig = BootstrapConfig.builder().runlist(runlist).build();

// Generate the bootstrap script to be executed in the VM (this will persist
// the configuration in a data bag under the key 'jclouds-chef' so it can be reused
// and then build the bootstrap script with the information in the configuration data bag)
chef.updateBootstrapConfigForGroup("jclouds-chef", bootstrapConfig);
Statement bootstrap = chef.createBootstrapScriptForGroup("jclouds-chef");

/* *** Finally create an SSH connection manually and run the script on the VM *** */

SshClient.Factory sshFactory = ctx.unwrap().utils()
    .injector().getInstance(Key.get(new TypeLiteral<SshClient.Factory>() {}));
SshClient ssh = sshFactory.create(HostAndPort.fromParts(vmIp, 22),
    LoginCredentials.builder().user(vmSshUsername).password(vmSshPassword).build());

ssh.connect();
try {
    String rawScript = bootstrap.render(OsFamily.UNIX);
    ExecResponse result = ssh.exec(rawScript);
} finally {
    ssh.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: Awesome, awesome answer @Ignasi Barrera - thanks and +1 (I **wish** I could upvote it more) - a few quick followups: (1) Can `vmIp` be the fully-qualified domain name of my VM (ex: `myapp01.me.example.com`, or does it *have* to be the VIP? If it *has* to be the VIP, is there a JClouds-Chef API for resolving the VIP from the FQDN? (2) I assume the `client` is the Chef client registered with our Chef server?

Comment: And (3) I'm not at all familiar with the concept of a `validator` - any chance you could provide a quick blurb about what these are, the functions they serve, and how I might ascertain what the value (the validator's name) of this field should be? Thanks again!

Comment: (1) You should be able to use the FQDN of the VM, as long as the DNS where you run the jclouds program can resolve it. (2) Yes, client is a client that must exist in the Chef Server. Clients in Chef are "api consumers". (3) The validator is a "special client" in all Chef Server installations that is used by the knife-bootstrap to register nodes in the Chef Server during their very first run. jclouds-chef just does the same that knife-bootstrap does.

Comment: Thanks again @Ignasi Barrera (+1 again) - Any idea where I could find these names on my Chef server? When I go to `http://mychef.me.example.com/clients` I see a list of clients. When I click on these clients I see their public keys. Are these what you're talking about? If so, what about the validators?

Comment: Yes, those are the clients. For the validator, there is the "something-validator". You need to use that name and its private key. If you don't have it stored anywhere you can regenerate it from the Chef Server UI. For the client, the same, there will be another "client" in there. You have to use its name and its private key. If you are using hosted Chef, the client and validator prefix is usually the name of your organization.

Comment: Thanks @Ignasi Barrer (+1 again). I *think* I get it now, but can you please confirm for me: if the VM name is `myapp01`, then it's client name (`client` variable above in your code) should be "myapp01", and its validator name (`validator` variable above) should be `myapp01-validator`, yes? I ask because I see scripts we have where we bootstrap nodes via knife, and the only params those scripts take is the client name and the role. So I *assume* the validator is always `<clientName>-validator`, yes? Thanks again!

Comment: No. When the bootstrap finishes you'll see a new node and client with the same name than your machine, but before that, a client must exist. Clients in Chef are "api users". When you use knife, the client and validator names are taken from the knife.rb config file. Those are the "users" (client and validator) knife uses to do its stuff; same for jclouds-chef. You have to use those.

Comment: Thanks again @Ignasi Barrera (+1) - I think I now understand the source of my confusion: when I bootstrap nodes manually, I usually do so with a command like: `knife bootstrap %machine_name% -N %machine_name% -x myadmin --sudo --run-list "role[somerole]"`. **If `%machine_name%` is the client name, then what would the validator name be?**

Comment: No. %machine_name% is not the client name. jclouds-chef will automatically generate a %machine_name% for you. When you use knife, it internally reads the configuration from the **knife.rb** file (it is usually located in /etc/chef or in a .chef/ folder in the current directory). That configuration file contains, apart from other configuration, the following properties: *node_name*, *client_key*, *validation_client_name* and *validation_key*. Those values are the ones you have to use for the client and validator names and keys.

Comment: Thanks again @Ignasi Barrera (+1) - OK here we go, please see my update iin the original question, it contains mmy `knife.rb` file. Here's the answer I need to give you the green check you so righteously deserve! : Based on the contents of my `knife.rb` file, what should the values be (in your code snippet above) for `client`, `validator`, `clientCredential` and `validatorCredential`? Thanks again here, *enormously*!

Comment: I've just edited the example program and changed the configuration to match the one provided in the knife.rb file and also added a couple properties to make sure there are no SSL issues.

Comment: I apologize for revoking the green check @Ignasi Barrera, I was assuming I would be able to get your code example to work. I have actually encountered an exception when running it. To make things fair for you, I will update my question and post a large bounty. If you can help me brute force this to work, the bounty is all yours!!

Comment: My apologies @Ignasi Barrera, it turns out I was having a classpath issue (wrong versions of different dependencies). Thank you for you help on this!